# PHP Log in page with hashed password issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I am trying to create a simple login structure, and im not sure why it does not work, I appreciate there are many examples on here, and please do not mark this for duplication, I just really need some help I have tried and tried but I can not see what I have done wrong.

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'databaseconnection.php';

$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$pwd = strip_tags($_POST['pwd']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$hash_pwd = $row['pwd'];
$hash = password_verify($pwd, $hash_pwd);

if ($hash == 0) {
  header("Location: error.php")
  exit();
} else {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$uid' AND pwd ='$hash_pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); {
  echo "your email address or password is incorrect!";
} else {
  $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
}

header("Location: profile.php")
```

If someone could simply suggest what changes I should make, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You can't "de-hash" a password. The whole point of hashing passwords is that it's a one-way operation.

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong phrase, but with password_verify does not that hash the entered password and check if its the same as the stored hash on the DB?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: When I fill in the log in page form, I get an error,  "this page is not working"

Comment: Verifies that the given hash matches the given password.

Comment: @DecaPeptyl, the phrase "this page is not working" doesn't appear anywhere in your code, and it doesn't sound like a standard error message. If that is your exact error message you may be looking in the wrong place. If it's an HTTP 500 error (which it might be) you need to look at your server logs and learn details about the error.

Comment: You must first select password from database based on username and compare it with password entered in form.

Comment: `if (!row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); {` that line for one thing, contains 2 errors and `header("Location: error.php")`

Answer (score 0):

*First check request second filter input third use pdo*

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    include 'databaseconnection.php';
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAILL); //filter input
    $pwd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pwd',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); //filter input
    $hashed = sha1($pwd);

    $sql= $conn->prepare( "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ? AND password = ?"); //use pdo here
    $sql->execute(array($email, $pwd));
    $row = $sql->fetch();

    if($row['email'] !== $email || $row['password'] !== $hashed){

      header("Location: error.php");
      exit();
    } else {

      $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
      header("Location: profile.php");
    }
    }else {
      echo 'error';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Muntadher thats great! but with regard to PDO? I am not familiar

Answer (score 0):

There you go simple code

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'databaseconnection.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$hash_pwd = $row['pwd']; // password from database

// if password is valid start session and redirect to profile.php
if (password_verify($pwd, $hash_pwd))
{
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    header('Location: profile.php');
}
else
{
    header("Location: error.php")
    exit();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the "} else {"... section.